# Bash + Python subprocess "declare"

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, popen

the following code returns: `/bin/sh: declare: not found`
Any help kindly appreciated.

### PS. Passing ["declare","-a"] or any combination of this sort doesn't work either.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

def dcl():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["declare -a ids"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
    proc_value = proc.communicate()[0];
    return proc_value
```

---

Ok, thanks for help. 
Passing `["declare","-a","ids"]` or `["declare","-a ids"]` didn't help. 
But, for a reason i don't get, adding:

```
executable = "/bin/bash"
```

SOLVED the problem. Yep, kinda weird. Anyway, appreciated!

Comment: `subprocess` uses `/bin/sh` by default. Perhaps `declare` is `bash`-specific, which is why you need to force its use using `executable="/bin/bash"`. (I'm not familiar enough with `sh` to know which parts of `bash` are new and specific to it.)

Comment: You'll have to explain to me what 'Any help kindly appreciated' means ;)

Answer (score 1):

try:

In process.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

def dcl():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["declare", "-a ids"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc_value = proc.communicate()[0]
    return proc_value

print dcl()
```

Execution with sample output:

```
[avasal@avasal]# python process.py
BASH=/bin/sh    
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=([0]="0")
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING=declare
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
. # More data
. # More data
. # More data
. # Some More data
_=/usr/bin/python

[avasal@avasal]#
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. 
Passing ["declare","-a","ids"] or ["declare","-a ids"] didn't help. 
But, for a reason i don't get, adding:
executable = "/bin/bash"
SOLVED the problem. Yep, kinda weird. Anyway, appreciated!